# Codeigniter at subfolder and htaccess for inner redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2, subdirectory

I have a project with custom engine at backend, I'm trying to hook every request at `/somewhere/` with my CodeIgniter. So I put my CI to `/www/somewhere/`, configured my CodeIgniter's .htaccess with new RewriteBase, so it now looks like:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /somewhere/

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

My CI creates static html for this project and stores it at `/compiled/`, so I have this structure

```
/www/
  /custom-engine/
  /img/
  /js/
  /somewhere/    <--- My CI's root
     /application/
     /system/
     /compiled/      <--- My storage for HTML
        my-file.html
        /my-compiled-folder/
        /one-more/
            /sub-compiled/
               index.html
```

And everything works fine. But. But I need to open my compiled files without `/compiled/` in URL.

Works: `http://domain.com/somewhere/compiled/one-more/sub-compiled/`

Need: `http://domain.com/somewhere/one-more/sub-compiled/`

I needn't redirect to my compiled folder/file, just open it. So I need add something to my .htaccess. Also I want keep access to my CI. For example I have controller `helloworld` and now it accessible from `http://domain.com/somewhere/helloworld/` (in fact I have administration panel for this `somewhere` here).

So.. I want to open files directly from my `/compiled/`, but also I need to save my CI. What should I add to my .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and working.

The idea is to verify `REQUEST_URI` other than `/system/` or `/application/` and see if it exists into `/compiled/` folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /somewhere/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somewhere/(system|application)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somewhere/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/somewhere/compiled/%1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/somewhere/compiled/%1 -f
RewriteRule . compiled/%1 [L]
```

You seem to avoid `/somewhere/` in your htaccess. Maybe you will have to avoid it in my code also (depends on server configuration)

Comment: Thanks! Works fine plus I learned something from Your answer. Glad to check Your answer as right and give bounty! Thanks again!

Comment: How can I deny access directly to my `/compiled/` `www.domain.com/somewhere/compiled/test.html` but grant access to `www.domain.com/somewhere/test.html`?